# PHP include html page charset problem

Tags: php, character-encoding, utf-8, diacritics

after querying a mysql db using the code below i have generated an html file:

```
    $myFile = "page.htm";
```

$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
  fwrite($fh, $row['text']);
  fclose($fh);

On the msql db the text is encoded using utf8_general_ci.
But i need to include it in a php web page as shown below:

```
 <?include('page.htm');?>
```

bearing in mind that the php web page uses utf8 charset on the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />
```

Now if i write on the db some letters with grave accent (è à ì) or a quote character and i open directly page.htm and on the db i see it all looking ok, but when i view it on the php page i see a question mark � character instead of those I originally wanted.
Why?!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

META charset isn't always solve the problem. Make sure your IDE saving real UTF-8 files. For exanple in Dreamweaver press CTRL-J then check Title/Encoding options.

Comment: I use Notepad++ and i save all the files in UTF8 (no BOM)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the encoding of the html page is actually set by the http response header 'Content-Type', to fix what you need to do is add the following to your PHP file before any output (ie at the top).

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8');
```

To clarify, that should be in the PHP that includes your html file, *not* in the html file you include :)

side point(s):

1. It's good practise to use the full opening tag <?php rather than <? as this isn't supported by all (many) servers
2. include is a statement not a function, so typically you'd write: include 'page.htm';

Comment: I have added this in the php webpage that generate html and also in the php webpage with the include but the problem persists.

Answer (score 4):

I solved adding this `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');` in the php webpage with the include.
I don't know why it works. I never used iso-8859-1 charset.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Bad practice, if you want include dynamically, you need to add header in all documents...

Comment: If that worked, and not charset=utf-8, then your document's encoding was probably not UTF-8.

Comment: It worked for me :) I created a check login page, in there at beginning of document just put the code and its everywhere! Thank you!

Comment: It works, as html document was some ANSI 1252 format and showing question marks. Problem fixed after adding it at the top. Thanks

Comment: @pirs Can you Pl elaborate why it is bad practice. He added header only in Master PHP page in which all the html documents will be loaded/included.

Comment: @Zeeshanef The problem of the question is `the files are not saved as utf8, so its not compatible with the database as utf8_general_ci` (global charset, chinese, accent etc.),that why its not a good solution to add in header "on the fly" a compatible charset like iso-8859-1 (french with accent) - bad fix, it will bring confusion in the project - better to save all files as utf8 in the project and it will work natively.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting stuff from a database, and it changes charset inexplicitly, note that in Php the actual connection charset to the db needs to be set explicitly to utf8 (if that's what you use), otherwise the content is converted while transfered, even if the content in the db itself is in correct format.. an interesting quirk ;)

Like so:
mysql_select_db($database, $connect);
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connect);  // set the connection charset.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably with a wrong encoding set in your mySQL database, or the database connection.

If your tables are all 100% `utf8_general_ci`, try doing a `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");` before doing any queries: That will set the connection to UTF-8.

Comment: I have also added mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;"); but nothing.

Comment: There is no probable solution to any generic UTF-8 issue.  Headers, content, escaping in HTML versus escaping in JSON versus escaping in input fields versus escaping in PUT versus escaping in MySQL -- there's no one thing to really look at.

Answer (score 1):

One point about your code:

when you use include, it is a php code, so you should include a php file, not a htm file:

```
<?include('page.php');?>
```

try changing the extension, I don't know how your code were working till now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try
separate includes blocks.
Ex mainpage.php:

```
<?php
 include("php1.php");
?>

<?php
 include("php2.php");
?>enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

I know i'm 10 years late for OP, but I encountered same problem. I was doing an include of a php file (I supose it's the same for html file) that wouldn't show utf-8. I couldn't use meta as this include comes after displaying html.

My way to solve:

1. Copied whole text of php into a new file.
2. Replaced original php with new file.

I hope it helps, i supose some meta data in original file was breakig everyting. But this is jsut a guess.